# Escape an infinite loop in a VB.NET recursion method that reads XML documents

Tags: xml, vb.net

Let's say I have 5 XML documents setup in the following manner.

**123.xml**

```xml
<link xlink="ABC">ABC</link>
<link xlink="DEF">DEF</link>
<link xlink="GHI">GHI</link>
```

**ABC.xml**

```xml
<link xlink="JKL">JKL</link>
```

**JKL.xml**

```xml
<link xlink="ABC">ABC</link>
```

**DEF.xml** and **GHI.xml** have no link tags in them.

In VB.NET, if I were calling these files recursively starting with 123.xml and my method call was as shown below, how would I go about getting out of the infinite loop caused by the JKL file calling back the ABC file in order to still get the DEF and GHI files that haven't been called in the recursion yet?  Keep in mind that this is just an example and the infinite loop could be caused any where within a large number of XML files so I won't always know that 123 is the file I need to get back to in order to still get the DEF and GHI files after escaping that infinite loop.

```
Public Sub Get_Next_Link(filename as String)
    Dim xDoc As New XmlDocument()
    xDoc.Load(filename)

    Dim xNodeList As XmlNodeList = xDoc.SelectNodes("//link")

    For Each xNode as XMLNode in xNodeList
       Get_Next_Link(get the xlink attribute and + ".xml" here)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: You could use a container to keep track of which files have already been visited, and only recurse into one if it hasn't already been visited.  If you just skip over the loop-back, then you presumably wouldn't need to remember anything about where to go back to.

Comment: To prevent an infinite loop, you would need to have some value that terminates the loop, in other words, something that signifies you have reached the end of your recursion and need to exit Get_Next_Link without making the call to Get_Next_Link, if you are iterating your xml's in a linear order, you could use the final xml file name as the terminating factor, or if you have a count of your total xmls, you could add to a counter variable in your function and when you reach your total exit the function without calling itself again.

Comment: @Craig, I like the idea but it's possible that somewhere down the line I will need to include an XML file that I have already visited.  The XML documents I am working with are a little ridiculous and unfortunately not able to be changed, otherwise I would just tell them to remove their infinite loop as it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: You can still use the same concept, but you'll need to keep additional meta-information to manage your control flow.  Exactly what kind of meta-information would, I think, depend on the exact details of when you still want to take an extra step in the loop (and then, what your exit condition is).

Comment: @Ryan Wilson, Unfortunately I do not want to prevent the infinite loop as I do need to look inside each document to determine if it has a link whether it's a loop or not.  Also, the files that are being opened are always different and can have hundreds of links within them so I really never know which one is the "final" one per se.  Since I'm calling these recursively I never know what my final count total will be until it's done.  This would be a lot easier if I could pull the entire XML tree but the links are in different documents so I am unaware of how to pull an entire tree for that.

Comment: @Craig, I will try that method out and see how it goes.  I do like the idea of knowing which files have already been reviewed.

Comment: @Craig, thanks for the information, I appreciate your time.  Joel's answer below appears to solve my problem.  I think it's the same thing you were saying Craig but the code saves me some thinking!  Again I appreciate the assistance!

Comment: Yes, Joel's answer is exactly what I was thinking of, if not necessarily exactly the way I was thinking to put it into practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not often I get to use VB.Net's `Static` keyword :)

```vb
Public Sub Get_Next_Link(filename as String)
    Static completed As new HashSet(Of String)()

    Dim xDoc As New XmlDocument()
    xDoc.Load(filename)

    Dim xNodeList As XmlNodeList = xDoc.SelectNodes("//link")

    For Each xNode as XMLNode in xNodeList
       Dim nextFile As String = 'get the xlink attribute and + ".xml" here
       If completed.Contains(nextFile) Then Continue
       completed.Add(nextFile)
       Get_Next_Link(nextFile)
    Next
End Sub
```

The one thing you may want to add to this is a way to reset the `completed` variable on separate recursive runs. I might be tempted to accomplish that via a delegate/closure:

```vb
Public Sub ReadXmlFiles(startFilename As String)

    Dim completed As New HashSet(Of String)()

    Dim NextLink As Action(Of String) = _ 
        Sub(fileName)
            Dim xDoc As New XmlDocument()
            xDoc.Load(filename)

            Dim xNodeList As XmlNodeList = xDoc.SelectNodes("//link")

            For Each xNode as XMLNode in xNodeList
               Dim nextFile As String = 'get the xlink attribute and + ".xml" here
               If completed.Contains(nextFile) Then Continue
               completed.Add(nextFile)
               NextLink(nextFile)
            Next
        End Sub   

    NextLink(startFileName)
End Sub
```

But that is probably needlessly complicated, when you can just put the `NextLink()` method as a private method in the same class. No need for the fancy lambda syntax. Still... you could argue this is clearer, because the it demonstrates that NextLink() only exists for ReadXmlFiles(), and it's useful in Stack Overflow to keep everything contained to a single method.

Comment: I just tested this out and it appears to be doing exactly what I need.  The only issue would be that if I needed one that's already been reviewed or is an "allowed duplicate" then it skips those, but I do have a function created to test for an "allowed duplicate" and should just be able to wrap that around the completed.Contains code to allow it to add it again.